# Merging tables across databases

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have to use merge command across different DB
i.e something like merge db1.user1.table_name to db2.user2.table_name
Both are oracle databases
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merge across a DB link works just like a "local" merge:

```
create database link test_dblink connect to <remote_user> 
  identified by <remote_pw> using '<remote_db_name>';


merge into user1.table1 loc_tab
using (select * from user2.table2@test_dblink) rem_tab
on (<merge_condition>)
when not matched then insert(...) values();
```